# How to get all the apple emoji list

Tags: ios, emoji

As the title says, how to get all the apple emoji list and convert to  NSString-Array. I downloaded a version from a website, but not contain all the emojis.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to look at the files that Unicode is providing itself. An easy to be parsed file can be found here:

https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.1/emoji-test.txt

Unicode Version 13.1